# Java lookup table design for multiple values

Tags: java, design-patterns

I need to create a lookup table in Java to return a value based on multiple parameters.

For example:

```
['THE VALUE I NEED', 'PARAM A', 'PARAM B' ,'PARAM C']
```

So based on the 3 params PARAM A, B. C, I need to retrieve a value.

I was looking at doing this with an Enum, but the the same key can be duplicated for example:

```
[RESULT 1, 'A' , 'B', 'C']
[RESULT 1, 'C' , 'B', 'C']
[RESULT 2, 'B' , 'C', 'A']
```

Whats the best way to implement this lookup table in Java, allowing for the duplicate key with different parameter configuration?

Comment: You can create you own class and use it as key (of course it require `hashCode` and `equals` implemented)

Comment: You can grow your own key - something like `Map.put("A|B|C",Result1)` should work in your case.

Comment: How do you handle the get( someNumber ), when one number can find multiple values? Do you want to return a collection then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stick with the enum, if your variables/parameters are static:

```
public enum LookupElement{

    ELEM_1("A","B","C", 1),
    ELEM_2("C","B","C", 1),
    ELEM_3("B","C","A", 2);

    private final String a;
    private final String b;
    private final String c;
    private final int value;

    LookupElement(String a, String b, String c, int v){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;        
        this.value = v;
    }

    public static LookupElement getByValue(int v){
        for(LookupElement e : values()){
            if(e.value == v) return e;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static LookupElement getByParams(String a, String b, String c){
        for(LookupElement e : values()){
            if(e.a.equals(a) && e.b.equals(b) && e.c.equals(c)) return e;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a nested class and a Map for this, in case you need a solution more flexible than an enum.

The key here is to create your own lightweight data class, in this case `Data` that would wrap around the values you want to map on, `a`, `b` and `c` here. You will need to overwrite the `equals` and `hashCode` function to incorporate all fields. Also, I would advice making these fields `final`. Changes to these fields will not automatically update the `HashTable` and might yield unexpected results. If you would need to create this lookup table once, you might want to look into wrapping the resulting map in a `Collections.unmodifiableMap`, to stop any of your classes from accidentally modifying the underlying collection.

```
  public static void main(String... args) {
    Map<Data, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(new Data("1", "A", "B"), "Value A");
    map.put(new Data("2", "F", "£"), "Value B");
    map.put(new Data("D", "A", "B"), "Value C");

    map.get(new Data("1", "A", "B")); // "Value A"

  }
```

`Data` class:

```
  public static class Data {
    private final String a;
    private final String b;
    private final String c;

    public Data(String a, String b, String c) {
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
      this.c = c;
    }

    public String getA() {
      return a;
    }

    public String getB() {
      return b;
    }

    public String getC() {
      return c;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      return a.hashCode() + 31 * b.hashCode() + 13 * c.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      return obj instanceof Data
               && Objects.equals(a, ((Data)obj).a)
               && Objects.equals(b, ((Data)obj).b)
               && Objects.equals(c, ((Data)obj).c);
    }
  }
```

Comment: The map's keys and values need to be swapped, so the OP can solve his problem with this solution. For example: map.put(new Data("A", "B", "C"), "Some Value");

Comment: This solution has 2 drawbacks, whose severity depend on the OP's usecase. Drawback 1: lookups will offently require the creation of a Data object and invoke many calls to instanceof. That's more overhead, than is actually necessary. Drawback 2: the hashcode method is broken, as it generates identical value, if the 2nd and 3rd parameter are swapped.

Comment: @SME_Dev if you want to hard code a lookup, then by all means, use an enum, however if these values are to change at any time, or if this is not an operation that is executed 100s of time a second, the overhead you mention is a small price to pay for flexibility.

Comment: I know its nitpicking, however on a weak android device, these are differences, that can make an app smoothly running, or lagging. By the way: enums aren't ultimate solution either, because you will end up iterating all options. For a huge list, they are significantly slower, than calculating an index via hashfunction.